# Can't get JQuery to work from JSFiddle?

Tags: jquery

I found an answer to what i need in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HpCWW/1/) however, when I place it in a document I can't get it to work. I've never used JQuery so its very new to me. Please help??

This is what my code looks like in the document.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$('.parent  div').hide();

$('#nav a').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).index('a'));
    var $div = $('.parent > div').eq($(this).index('#nav a'));
    $div.show();
    $('.parent > div').not($div).hide();
});
</script>
<!--Footer and Navigation Div's-->
<div id="bg"><img src="images/bg.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>S.E. <span>yoga</span></p>
            <div id="nav">
                <ul><a href="#">Link 1</a></ul>
                <ul><a href="#">Link 2</a></ul>
                <ul><a href="#">Link 3</a></ul>
                <ul><a href="#">Link 4</a></ul>
            </div>
    </div>

<!--END Footer and Navigation Div's-->

<div class="parent">
    <div class="a">
        <p>this is a</p>
    </div>   
    <div class="b">
        <p>this is b</p>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
        <p>this is c</p>
    </div>
    <div class="d">
        <p>this is d</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You aren't including the [JQuery library](https://jquery.com/download/).

Comment: Also you'll probably want to wrap your jquery code in `$(function() { /* your code goes in here */ });` to ensure it runs when the page has been rendered.  It's possible that when you call `$('#nav a').click(...` that `#nav a` may not be there. `$(function() { ... })` will run your code when the browser says it's done rendering everything.

Comment: OK look at his Fiddle! HE ALREADY HAS THE LIBRARY SETUP! All he needs is what MushinNoShin and I have already said `$(function() ({});

Comment: "Can't get JQuery to work from JSFiddle?" is the question. In jsFiddle you don't put script tags in the head, in jsFiddle you do not put any script at the closing body tag!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1: you aren't including jQuery

Problem 2: You have to put the script below the html, right before the closing `</body>` tag. The two selectors you have aren't found if you run the script as it is now.

```
<head>
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<!--Footer and Navigation Div's-->
<div id="bg"><img src="images/bg.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>S.E. <span>yoga</span></p>
            <div id="nav">
                <ul><a href="#">Link 1</a></ul>
                <ul><a href="#">Link 2</a></ul>
                <ul><a href="#">Link 3</a></ul>
                <ul><a href="#">Link 4</a></ul>
            </div>
    </div>

<!--END Footer and Navigation Div's-->

<div class="parent">
    <div class="a">
        <p>this is a</p>
    </div>   
    <div class="b">
        <p>this is b</p>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
        <p>this is c</p>
    </div>
    <div class="d">
        <p>this is d</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.parent  div').hide();

$('#nav a').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).index('a'));
    var $div = $('.parent > div').eq($(this).index('#nav a'));
    $div.show();
    $('.parent > div').not($div).hide();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I do have one more question. It appears to not work on IE, I've heard that the console.log is one of the problems with that. Is there a way to make this IE compatible?

Comment: If you need this to work in old versions of ie,  change the jQuery version to 1.11.3 within the script tag that imports jquery@user5166162

Comment: Thanks for your help! it is greatly appreciated!